# Magento 2: Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: magento2.3, error, customer-account, rest-api, dependency-injection

I had created a custom API for adding new customer in Magento 2.3. I had injected dependency injection and passed the method to create the customer account. But it gives me below error:

> main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: MyModule\Customapi\Model\Addcustomer, Too few arguments to function MyModule\Customapi\Model\Addcustomer::__construct(), 7 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116 and exactly 8 expected [] []

I had injected `CustomerRepositoryInterface` to add new customer like this:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Customapi\Model;
use MyModule\Customapi\Api\AddCustomerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;

class AddCustomer implements AddCustomerInterface
{
    protected $request;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $dataHelper;
    protected $accountManagementInterface;
    protected $authentication;
    private $accountConfirmation;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $_customerFactory;
    protected $_customerInterfaceFactory;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Data $dataHelper,
        RequestInterface $request,
        AccountConfirmation $accountConfirmation = null,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagementInterface,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerInterfaceFactory
    ) {
        $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->dataHelper =$dataHelper;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->accountManagementInterface = $accountManagementInterface;
        $this->accountConfirmation = $accountConfirmation ?: $objectManager
            ->get(AccountConfirmation::class);
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_customerInterfaceFactory = $customerInterfaceFactory;
    }

    public function addcustomer()
    {
        ...
        $customer = $this->_customerInterfaceFactory->create();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: add more code please

Comment: Hey @AsharRiaz, I had updated the code. Can you please check and suggest me the proper solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compile your **dependency injection** that is di.xml
Try this

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
rm -rf var/generation/*
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to remove all generated files. The problem is the scope has changed but Magento is not updated about this yet.

Running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` will clear the generated folder for you. Depending on what version of Magento you are on this will be in var/generated or generated/

If you have Magento in a "compiled" mode you will have to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `,` after `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerFactory` it should be like below.

```
public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Data $dataHelper,
        RequestInterface $request,
        AccountConfirmation $accountConfirmation = null,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagementInterface,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerInterfaceFactory
    )
```

Hope it'll solve your issue. Let me know if you still face any problem on this.

Comment: No, It was my mistake just c&p issue. i had already used the `,` in my code. Thanks for pointing @MayankZalavadia